# Enemy manager class AS3

Tags: windows, actionscript-3, gamekit

How can I make a enemy that moving across the line and throwing something to our player?

I want to do it with ActionScript 3, and I already have `enemy_manager` class
I already have this code for getting angle

```
var dx : Number = point1.x - point2.x;
var dy : Number = point1.y - point2.y;
var angleInRadians : Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
var andleInDegrees : Number = angleInRadians * (180 / Math.PI);
```

Comment: By throwing, do you mean shooting something in a straight line ?  Throwing sounds like it should be arcing like if I threw a baseball.

Comment: What is your problem? the animation?

Answer (score 0):

What I think that your asking is how to get decimal values to multiple by the projectiles speed to make the projectile go towards the player. This is the code to accomplish that.

```
        var projectileSpeed:Number=30 (pixels a second)
        var dx : Number = point2.x - point1.x;
        var dy : Number = point2.y - point1.y;
        var angleInRadians : Number = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        var angleInDegrees : Number = angleInRadians * (180 / Math.PI);

        this.directionX = Math.cos(angleInRadians) * projectileSpeed; // Turns the angleInRadians into a decimal value
        // For example ( 180 degrees would be 1 PI and the cos() and sin() would make directionX=-1 and directionY=0
        this.directionY = Math.sin(angleInRadians) * projectileSpeed;

        projectile.rotation = angleInDegrees; // makes it face where it is going ( if you event want this)
        ...
        private function loop(e:Event):void { // loop to show the projectile move
          // Updates the projectile's positions using directionX and directionY
          projectile.x += directionX;
          projectile.y += directionY;
    }
```